# Fisher information matrix in logistic regression

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization, weibull-distribution, fisher-scoring

I am self-studying the basics of logistic regression. I came across this sentence:

> In logistic regression expected and observed information matrixes are
>   equal

I am aware that the information matrix is part of the MLE, namely the second derivative of the log likelihood function.

I came across that statement when I was trying to understand the difference between Newton-Raphson algorithm and Fisher scoring algorithm as optimization algorithms. In Weibull distribution the optimization algorithms are necessary to find the maximum. This leads to my another question:

Why MLE for Weibull distribution cannot be determined analytically?

Comment: Can you please provide the source of that statement? (I can "almost readily" accept that they are assumed to be asymptotically equivalent but I am not certain about "equal") +1 Nice question.

Comment: These are really two different questions, and you should split them and post them separately!

Comment: @usεr11852 i got it from my professors script. It is within the context of MLE in Beneralized linear models, where asymptotic normality applies.

Comment: @jbowman i though there is a link, fixing it now then.